# Adding time as a variable into a date - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript code that compares the difference between the current date and time and an event date and start time.

It then works out the difference in days, hours, minutes and seconds between the two dates.

The date is split from the time and whilst manually entering the time works:

```
var compareDate = new Date("<?php echo $qdate->format('D M j Y 13:30:00'); ?>");
```

If I try to add in the time as a variable:

```
var compareDate = new Date("<?php echo $qdate->format('D M j Y $startTime'); ?>");
```

It doesn't work.

I have echoed the variable to the screen and it shows as expected but how can I insert it as a variable into that date and time?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Try it with double quotes like this `... format("D M j Y $startTime") ...`

Comment: Even if your code works, it isn't the correct way. Use one of the formats described on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: What these guys above said. To make it a bit easier, store the right information in a variable earlier in your page rather than inlined in the javascript: `<?php $startdatetime = $qdate->format( .... ); ?>`. Then, in the script, you just have to echo the variable using `<?php echo $startdatetime;?>`, or even just `<?=$startdatetime?>`. That will decrease the risk of errors like this, caused by mixing complex expressions from two scripting languages.

Comment: Hi all.  Thanks for your help and comments.  All taken on board.  I don't believe you can accept a comment as an accepted answer so @Anubhav if you add it as an answer, I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with double quotes like this `... format("D M j Y $startTime") ...` as PHP interprets variables inside double quotes.